# I2C scanner freeze on "scanning ..." when using different addresses for MPR121

Tags: arduino, i2c

so i'm using an MPR121 sensor and an Arduino. the ADD pin of the MPR121 is connected to GND so it means that it's address is 0x5A and the I2C scanner works just fine but the problem is that when i connect ADD pin to change MPR121 address the I2C scanner program freezes on "scanning ...".

here's where i got my I2C  scanner code from
https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/

schema :

SCL → A5
SDA→ A4
ADD → GND, 3.3v, SCL, SDA
IRQ → pin 4

Comment: Arduino typically works at 5 V. MPR121 depending on the setup operates at 2.0 V to 3.6 V or 1.71 V to 2.75 V, see its datasheet, for example here:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/MPR121.pdf
Do you use some level converter? Connecting the pins to different other pins may be problematic because of these voltage levels.
Also, I assume you have done a complete power down after changing the ADDR pin?

Comment: yes i did and i'm using 3.3v

Comment: please read the description of the [arduino] tag

Comment: I would try checking the connections first once again and then commenting out the line "if (error == 0)" so that addresses get printed even if no device is detected at that address. When does it freeze? Does it check some addresses first, doest it freeze at 0x5A, or later?

Comment: i did, and it just prints every i2c address on the arduino, now the problem is that this device mpr121 has 0X5A address by default which the scanner detects and print but when i connect add pin in that device to 3.3v or scl or sda so the address change to 0X5B for example the scanner stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] it was because of hard wiring, the solder bridges on the back of the MPR121 were badly welded.